# knockoutjs adding observables after binding

Tags: knockout.js

I have a nested object which I make it an observable with the mapping plugin. However, when I update the object and it includes new properties, these are not reflected in the UI

```
function Model(data){
            var self = this;
            ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);

            self.printName = ko.computed(function(){
                return self.changes.name;
            })

            self.printAge = ko.computed(function(){
                if(self.changes.age)
                    return self.changes.age;
            })

            self.refresh = function(data){
                ko.mapping.fromJS(data, self);
            }
        }
        $(function(){
            var data = {
                changes:{
                    name: "User"
                }
            }
             model = new Model(data);
            ko.applyBindings(model)
        })

<div data-bind="text: printName()"></div>
<div data-bind="text: printAge()"></div>
```

The above, when rendered prints the name. I understand that age has not become an observable because it was not contained in the initial data.

At some point I receive a new object from the server, which now has the age attribute and I refresh the model with

```
model.refresh(data)
```

but of course the UI is not updated.

What is the common way of handling such cases. The example I provide is simplified. In reality the object is more complicated. Do I need to pass default values, making them observable and whenever new data come in, I will be fine? I think this is going to work but is there another way that does not require something like that? A way to make these new attributes bind dynamically

Thanks

Comment: The whole point of having a view model is that it reflects all things that can appear on the screen. If your base data (the model) sometimes does not have a certain property (like, `age`), the view model should still have a slot (an observable) and a default value for that property. Once you do that, your view will start to work.

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/Sh4Z6/, that's how I would approach this.

Comment: Thanks.  So it seems that I need to supply default values

Comment: Well, at least for everything you want to display unconditionally. You can cheat your way around with `<!-- ko if: $data.change.age -->` but that's not really clean, IMHO.

Comment: I agree with you. Going with defining a default schema